PMD analysis failing incomplete auxclasspath: Error while processing methods java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
I am trying to perform PMD analysis through Azure Pipeline and I am getting the attached error.
The java version is set to Java 17 and the maven goal is **goals: -e clean package pmd:check ** .Below are the entries for maven-pmd plugin(3.14.0) and pmd-java dependencies PMD version(6.37.0). maven-compiler-plugin is set to 3.13.0.
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.14.0</version>
  <configuration>
  <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
 <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
 <version>6.37.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
 <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
 <version>6.37.0</version>
</dependency>
<maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.13.0</version>

Below are the details on the logs:
Possible incomplete auxclasspath: Error while processing methods
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3288664Z java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3288965Z     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3289321Z     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:3402)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3289683Z     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods (Class.java:2504)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3290111Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.MethodTypeResolution.getApplicableMethods (MethodTypeResolution.java:473)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3290567Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit (ClassTypeResolver.java:398)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3291175Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTName.jjtAccept (ASTName.java:38)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3291760Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3292208Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3292672Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:403)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3293332Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit (ClassTypeResolver.java:1074)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3293806Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTPrimaryPrefix.jjtAccept (ASTPrimaryPrefix.java:48)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3294264Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit (ClassTypeResolver.java:882)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3294731Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTPrimaryExpression.jjtAccept (ASTPrimaryExpression.java:25)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3295372Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3296691Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3297241Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:478)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3297875Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit (ClassTypeResolver.java:1219)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3298349Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTStatementExpression.jjtAccept (ASTStatementExpression.java:25)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3298951Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3299403Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3300048Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:448)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3300508Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTStatement.jjtAccept (ASTStatement.java:25)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3300974Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3301415Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3301937Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:463)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3302382Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlockStatement.jjtAccept (ASTBlockStatement.java:25)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3303168Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3303776Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3304237Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:458)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3304639Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlock.jjtAccept (ASTBlock.java:27)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3305059Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3305628Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3306413Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:448)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3306931Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTStatement.jjtAccept (ASTStatement.java:25)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3307342Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3307783Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3308247Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:493)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3308687Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTIfStatement.jjtAccept (ASTIfStatement.java:93)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3309100Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3309551Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3310005Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:448)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3310433Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTStatement.jjtAccept (ASTStatement.java:25)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3310863Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3311285Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3311911Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:463)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3312358Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlockStatement.jjtAccept (ASTBlockStatement.java:25)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3312792Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3313326Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3314011Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:458)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3314455Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlock.jjtAccept (ASTBlock.java:27)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3314890Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3315349Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3316194Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:238)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3316750Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTMethodDeclaration.jjtAccept (ASTMethodDeclaration.java:37)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3317217Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3317725Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3318361Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:58)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3318828Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration.jjtAccept (ASTClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration.java:44)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3319306Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3319757Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3320216Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:53)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3320674Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceBody.jjtAccept (ASTClassOrInterfaceBody.java:35)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3321903Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3322405Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3322878Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:23)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3323366Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.jjtAccept (ASTClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.java:56)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3323849Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3324299Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3324931Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:208)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3326332Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit (ClassTypeResolver.java:253)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3327198Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTTypeDeclaration.jjtAccept (ASTTypeDeclaration.java:39)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3327760Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept (AbstractJavaNode.java:62)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3328229Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:13)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3328707Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit (JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:183)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3329168Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit (ClassTypeResolver.java:224)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3329816Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTCompilationUnit.jjtAccept (ASTCompilationUnit.java:44)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3330260Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.TypeResolutionFacade.initializeWith (TypeResolutionFacade.java:21)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3330838Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.AbstractJavaHandler$5.start (AbstractJavaHandler.java:119)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3331279Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.usesTypeResolution (SourceCodeProcessor.java:163)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3331703Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource (SourceCodeProcessor.java:190)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3332146Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCodeWithoutCache (SourceCodeProcessor.java:107)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3332567Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode (SourceCodeProcessor.java:89)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3333004Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode (SourceCodeProcessor.java:51)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3333405Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.processor.PmdRunnable.call (PmdRunnable.java:78)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3333799Z     at net.sourceforge.pmd.processor.PmdRunnable.call (PmdRunnable.java:24)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3334153Z     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3334583Z     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:539)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3335158Z     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3335562Z     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3335963Z     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3336494Z     at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:840)
2024-04-04T11:55:14.3337123Z Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level

Request your quick help on this since this is required on priority for us.
Kind Regards,
Renjini
I have tried changing the versions , setting auxclass path.

I'd first try to update maven-pmd-plugin and PMD and see, if the issue goes away. m-pmd-p 3.14.0 is from 2020-10-24, PMD 6.37.0 is from 2021-07-31.
Try using the latest versions: maven-pmd-plugin 3.21.2 and PMD 6.55.0.
The underlying issue (NoClassDefFoundError) might be caused for a couple of reasons:

incomplete auxclasspath. The auxclasspath will be determined automatically by the maven-pmd-plugin, so you don't need extra configuration for that. The new m-pmd-p version might contain some fixes in this area. A newer PMD version might also handle such situations more gracefully.
incompatible Java versions: PMD 6 loads the referenced classes into the running JVM, in order to introspect the classes via reflection. If you are running Maven with an older JVM than you might run into that problem. In that case, you might need to update Java as well. Since you mention, that your project is using Java 17, you should use at least Java 17 to run Maven to avoid such problems. (There are also some tricks possible involving toolchains)

